# document.querySelector is not working in module js file

Tags: javascript, module, queryselector

If the type of my app.js file (which is connected with the html page) is "module" then document.querySelector are not working. If i remove type as module, then it works fine. but I want to use querySelectors for the app functionality and import functions from other modules, how would i do that???

thanks

Comment: You need to post your code for permit us to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.